# Login page for admin and different user type

Tags: android

I am trying to make a registration page in android studio for three different kind of users. (1). admin itself (2). user type 1 (3). user type 2. i want that depending upon the credential it should get redirected to their respective activities. how can i do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say that every user is saved in a database and every entity from db has a column type which is 1,2 or 3. So, when a login is successful you will check the db to see if the credentials are ok and return the type of the user. From this point, your android code will be like this

```
 Intent intent;
 switch(userType) {
 case 1:
     intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, AdminActivity.class);
     break;
 case 2:
     intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, User1Activity.class);
     break;
 case 3:
    intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, User3Activity.class);
    break;
}
startActivity(intent);
```